# Object.writeFileSync - Received type number

Tags: node.js, fs, node-js-14

I have old monolith app written in NodeJS.

It requires lots of node_modules.

Application is exiting, because of unhandled exception which is happening in some of the modules.

```
You have triggered an unhandledRejection, you may have forgotten to catch a Promise rejection: undefined


TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received type number (22388)    
    at Object.writeFileSync (node:fs:2146:5)
    at ProcessContainer (/usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/ProcessContainer.js:67:8)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/ProcessContainer.js:100:3)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:79:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

For now I have included this code in hope that it will give me stack trace:

```
process.on('uncaughtException', (e) => {
  logger.error(e.stack || e, `uncaughtException happened`);
  process.exit(1);
});
```

Problem is it takes several days/weeks for error to occur.

Did anyone had similar/same issue?
Is there a way to globally override function of some module?
If this is possible it would be easy for me to create a wrapped function with try catch.

I use NodeJS 14, 16 has same issue. I can't rollaback node version

I will try with this. However I am unsure if it overrided fs.writeFileSync everywhere

```
import fs from 'fs';

const f = fs.writeFileSync;
delete fs.writeFileSync;
fs.writeFileSync = (fileName, data, options) => {
  try {
    logger.debug({ fileName }, `Overriding writeFileSync function`);
    f(fileName, data, options);
  } catch (err) {
    logger.error({ err: err.stack || err, fileName }, 'Error in writing file');
  }
};
```